# Auto refering nesting with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I have this model in Django (based on a legacy database):

```
class NationalTest(models.Model):
    unityId = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    parentId = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    grade = models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

This model stores the grade that a "unity" (a school, a city, a region or a state in our country) received in a national test. `unityId` is the id of the unity, `grade` is its grade in the test, and `parentId` is the id of its upper parent (i.e.: if our unity is a school, `parentId` the id of the city where the school is located; if it's a city, `parentId` is the id of the state where the city is located, and so on).

For front-end purposes, when I fetch some school's grade, I need also the grade of the city, the state, the region and the whole country (all 5 levels possible). When I fetch a city's grade I need state, region and country's grade too. When I fetch state's grade, just need the two levels above grade.

I think that the best way I can solve it is to create a nested serializer based on `parentId`. I know how to do it when we have a foreign key from another model, but **how can I do that when the foreign key is in the same model (i.e.: it's the `unityId`)?**

I need something like this to be fetched:

```
{
   unityId: 2393044, // It is a school
   parentId: 239, // In this case, it is a city
   grade: 7.3,
   city: {
      unityId: 239
      parentId: 23
      grade: 8.2,
   },
   state: {
      unityId: 23
      parentId: 2
      grade: 7.5,
   },
   region: {
      unityId: 2
      parentId: 1
      grade: 7.9,
   },
   country: {
      unityId: 1
      parentId: null
      grade: 7.7,
   },
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using a a ForeignKey to the parentId?@André Carvalho

Comment: @EliakinCosta it works if it is a legacy database?

Comment: Yes, it works. You should look into inspectdb for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should have to use SerializerMethodField.

   ```
   class NationalTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
       parent= serializers.SerializerMethodField()

       class Meta:
           model = NationalTest

       def get_parent(self, obj):
           # get the information of parent.
   ```
2. You can use ForeignKey with own Model

   ```
   parentId= models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   ```

Comment: How do I "get the information of parent" in the `SerializerMethodField` case?

Comment: You can access parentId in the following way.
`self.parentId`.
In other words, `self` refers to the current Model Instance